# How to install splash screen in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFwVz.png)

because in my end I already follow the automatic installation instruction but still it won't work https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen Does anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You have a typo in `npm`

Comment: rnpm link react-native-splash-screen is this line?  npm link react-native-splash-screen this should I run in my terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The react-native-splash-screen is very old and not maintained for a very long time. Instead use [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash). There also installation guide on the github page and youtube

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I hope this will work now I have already tried several tries installing splash screen. I'll get back to you as soon as I try.